# How to save a textbox in php as an array?

Tags: php, arrays, post, textbox

Is there anyway to save a textboxs as an array similar to how multiple checkboxs  can be saved as an array? When you save multiple checkboxs to an array the value only comes up in the array when the checkbox has a check in it. Is this the same with textboxs? Do they only have value when they're not empty?

I'm trying to save these textboxs as an array (I only took the part of the form that you all need to see)

```
<form action="formemail.php" method="POST" name="rcr">
<td><input type="text" name="desc[]" id="desc"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="desc[]" id="desc"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="desc[]" id="desc"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="desc[]" id="desc"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="sendwork" id="sendwork" value="Send Work Order"></td>

</form>
```

In the next page I'm trying to take these values and just output them in a simple way (later I'm going to be adding them to an email using foreach if I can)..... below is formemail.php

```
<?php
$description = $_POST["desc"];
echo $description[0];
echo $description[1];
?>
```

I can't get anything to echo for the life of me. And I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I just ran your code and I could get the PHP to echo the text field contents. Try adding `print_r($_POST)` and checking F12->Network and seeing if the correct fields are being submitted. Maybe, some JavaScript or something else is messing with your form submission.

Comment: If they are empty (no text), then they will echo as an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

tried ?

```
   if(  isset( $_POST["desc[]"] )  ) echo "is set ; )";
```

btw. same multiple id's can cause you problems if you work with JS/JQuery.

Comment: `$_POST["desc[]"]` is incorrect. This should be `$_POST["desc"]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `foreach` and test submitted values:

```
foreach($_POST['desc'] as $post)
{
    echo !empty($post) ? $post.'<br />' : 'An empty value.<br />';
}
```